# GitLab CI jobs fail when docker executor is used but pass with shell executor

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have set up a GitLab CI with two runners - one of them uses docker executor, while the other one uses shell. The runner with shell executor works fine, however, the docker one fails every time after the `./gradlew.bat --stop` step because of errors in gradlew.bat.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 25s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
$ ./gradlew.bat --stop
./gradlew.bat: line 1: @rem: command not found
./gradlew.bat: line 2: @rem: command not found
./gradlew.bat: line 3: @rem: command not found
./gradlew.bat: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./gradlew.bat: line 4: `@rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");'
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

YAML file:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd myproject/
    - ./gradlew build -x test
    - ./gradlew.bat --stop

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd myproject/
    - ./gradlew test
    - ./gradlew.bat --stop
```

Comment: If you're using Linux docker containers, that would probably explain it. You can't run `.bat` files on Linux. Meanwhile, your shell runner is fine most likely because you installed the runner on a Windows machine, which can run `.bat` files.

Comment: @sytech That's correct - I am using a Linux docker container for the GitLab runner. I was not aware that running batch files on Linux is not possible but now it's fixed. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be caused by me trying to execute a batch file (.bat) in a Linux docker container.

I fixed the problem by changing `- ./gradlew.bat --stop` to `- ./gradlew --stop` in the YAML file.

According to to the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper) the `gradlew.bat` and `gradlew` perform the same job where the .bat is intended for use with Windows.